# git gc out of memory

Tags: git

I have to clean-up my git repository with `git gc`. Unfortunately I do get a fatal out of memory error.

```
ernst@samson:~/htdocs/stockdoo$ git gc
Counting objects: 42368, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (24700/24700), done.
fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed   
error: failed to run repack
```

This is with git 1.7.4 on Ubuntu 10.4.

Any ideas to get arround this problem?

Comment: What version of Git are you using, and on which OS are you using it?

Answer (score 2):

On a 64-bit OS, `git` requires a huge amount of **virtual** memory to run `git-gc`, about 8GB. Normally, nobody limits virtual memory on a 64-bit OS because that kind of defeats the whole point of having a 64-bit OS, but some "uneducated" sysadmins or users do so. If you have a resource limit on virtual memory that's less than 64GB or so, find the person who set it and hit them with a clue bat.

One of the main benefits of 64-bit operating systems is that it means address space is not a scarce resource.

I believe newer versions of `git` have a fix for this, but the problem is really not in `git` at all.

Comment: In any multiuser system it is absolutely must to limit virtual memory usage if you are responsible sysadmin. Otherwise any rogue or mistakenly written program can easily initiate OOM killer which could be the worst thing that can happen

Comment: @Cougar: Clean pages of virtual memory can never trigger the OOM killer. You can limit backed pages if you want.

Comment: I wish I could downvote this answer (not enough rep). The problem is definitely in git itself. Why does cleanup routine require !!!8 GB!!! of memory? It's not reasonable. And why do you think the problem with virtual memory? The problem is that git cannot get enough free memory.

Comment: @anton_rh When you say that using 8GB of memory is not reasonable, you are talking about physical memory, that is, RAM. The problem is not that git cannot get enough free memory, it's that git cannot get enough virtual memory. Please read my answer again, particularly the first sentence. On modern OSes, virtual memory is not a scarce resource and so developers seldom put any effort into minimizing it. A 64-bit app, for example, could decide to memory map 8GB of files. Why not? That will use 8GB of virtual memory and if someone puts a vm limit on the app, it'll run out of "memory".

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I didn't put any VM limitations on the system (actually, I've never heard of such limitations). At 99% the entire system starts to work very slowly (I think because it is actively using swap). So I guess the problem is with physical memory, not with virtual. If `git` didn't need so much memory, I guess it would not `malloc`ate it.

Comment: @anton_rh I have no idea what problem you are talking about. You may have a problem that has something to do with physical memory. But the problem the original poster was having was due to virtual memory exhaustion. Your last sentence shows that you still don't understand the point I'm trying to make. The `malloc` function allocates virtual memory, not physical memory. So yes, `git` needed lots of virtual memory. That was my point.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, the `malloc` function allocates virtual memory, but when the allocated memory is accessed, the kernel allocates physical memory and maps virtual memory to physical memory. And usually you don't `malloc`ate memory which you don't use later (don't access it).